# Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

When trying to deploy VS solution facing

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Remote SharePoint site connections are not supported

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to make sure.

- make sure the account under which u are deploying the solution is in local admin group on the sharepoint server
- also user account should have permission on db server
- check the property of the visual studio project and make sure sharepoint site URL mentioned here
- also add the user in policy of web app in sharepoint

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/8aa7f469-fc5b-4a00-8fb1-0ef9432c8c71/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-application-pool-cannot-connect-to-the-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

http://sharepointserved.blogspot.com/2016/06/error-occurred-in-deployment-step.html